# Could I use SplashScreenImage.png file as my wp7 application start-up screen image?

Tags: windows-phone-7, splash-screen

Could I use SplashScreenImage.png file as my wp7 application start-up screen image?

Is any way to use png file as SplashScreenImage ?

Answer (score 6):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680265%28v=pandp.11%29.aspx):

> To add your own splash screen image, replace SplashScreenImage.jpg
>   with a JPG that has a size of 480 by 800 pixels.

Seems like it has to be a JPG. Is there a reason you want to use a PNG instead? The only reason I can think of is transparency, but that wouldn't be useful since the page behind wouldn't have loaded anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more complex splash screen a solution can be to remove the already existing splash screen image from the project (this will remove the splash screen) and make the first page you navigate to a splash screen page - now here you can do whatever you want. Add a `DispatcherTimer` to it and navigate to your main page once the time runs out.

For a simple splash screen do what keyboardP said, replace the SplashScreenImage.jpg with one of your own making sure it's size is 480 by 800.